# What methods are available to tamper with cookies in firefox 6?

Tags: php, mysql, firefox, cookies

I need to do some testing for a website made in php/mysql and wanted to know the best way I can tamper with cookies in firefox 6.  There were some addons that were available to previous versions but are not longer supported in firefox 6.

**What methods do you recommend to tamper with cookies in firefox 6?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Firecookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/) works with Firebug and works in my Firefox 6.

[image: Firecookie in Firefox 6]

Comment: Thanks Alex, any methods or things you do often with it?

Comment: @LedZeppelin: Mainly to ensure cookies are being set and have the correct values without looking at all the HTTP traffic. You can modify the values easily with it too.

Answer (score 2):

The Web Developer toolbar addon might be helpful:

http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

Also can be improved with Toggole web:
http://barisderin.com/?p=613

Answer (score 1):

[Cookies Manager+](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/cookies-manager-plus/), continuation of abandoned *Add N Edit Cookies*.

It's standalone (not Firebug extension), you can search by domain - useful e.g. f you're working with a multi-domain site which does a lot of redirects and for instance want to delete cookies from all that domains before launching an URL.

Screenshot from addons.mozilla.org:

[image: Cookies Manager+]

Comment: Thanks for the answer even though a best answer was selected!